# Why do I get redirected to the Forbidden page when clicking on form fields?

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4

I am building a simple little personal site, and for the site I am making a modal contact form with Bootstrap. When I open the modal and click on any of the form fields, I am immediately redirected to the Forbidden page and see the error message "You don't have permission to access /none" on this server.". I can't for the life of me understand why this would happen. Below is the form modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="contact-form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contact-form" aria-hidden="true" style="color:darkslategray;">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Shoot me a message!</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Contact form -->
        <form method="POST" action="index.php">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" id="name" />

            <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control mb-4" name="email" id="email" />

            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control mb-4" name="message" id="message"></textarea>

          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And below is the HTML for the link that triggers the modal:

```
<p>Want to chat? <span class="contact" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contact-form">Contact me</span>.</p>
```

Could someone please help me understand why this is happening and how I can fix it? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably have a `click` event-handler set-up somewhere on a parent element that performs the redirect. Use your browser's "Event listener breakpoints" to see where it is. You'll want to select `click` and `mousedown`.

Comment: @Dai there are no other event listeners that I have included. Bootstrap comes with its own JS included. Any click event anywhere after the modal box is opened is bubbling to somewhere and causing the error. No idea how it's happening.